# Laravel, how to convert a collection object into a builder object

Tags: laravel, collections, builder

I need to use paginate and simplepaginate on a collection, so i'm trying to convert the collection into a builder object.
To do so I am thinking of creating a function that gets the id of every item in the collection and then builds a query with it, but that seemed to me like a lot of resources waisted,
Is there a simpler way ?

Comment: If you could provide some example that would be awesome... regenerating a collection to a builder is not a good idea... its better to paginate a collection directly when fetching a collection from the database.. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#introduction

Answer (score 2):

A better way to do this is to [build paginator object manually](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator) using the existing collection.

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination#manually-creating-a-paginator):

> Sometimes you may wish to create a pagination instance manually, passing it an array of items. You may do so by creating either an `Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator` or  `Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator` instance, depending on your needs.
>
> The `Paginator` class does not need to know the total number of items in the result set; however, because of this, the class does not have methods for retrieving the index of the last page. The `LengthAwarePaginator` accepts almost the same arguments as the `Paginator`; however, it does require a count of the total number of items in the result set.
>
> In other words, the `Paginator` corresponds to the `simplePaginate` method on the query builder and Eloquent, while the `LengthAwarePaginator` corresponds to the paginate method.

Answer (score 1):

Building on what Alexey said, as alternative, you can build a Paginator from a collection manually. This is a simpler way without the waste of an additional query. e.g.

```
 // Collection $collection
 
$perPage       = 10;
$currentPage   = Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?? 1;
$itemsOnPage   = $collection->skip(10 * ($currentPage-1))->take($perPage);
$paginatorPath = Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::resolveCurrentPath();

$paginator     = new \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator(
        $itemsOnPage,
        $collection->count(),
        $perPage,
        $currentPage,
        ['path' => $paginatorPath]
    );
```

Then in your view,

```
        {!! $paginator->render() !!}
```

Comment: The title of this question is "how to convert a collection object into a builder object" and the bounty request is "Looking for an answer that explicitly answers the question, rather than alternative approaches." -- The answer should not be about building new paginator instances.

Comment: Actually, if you edit your answer so I can vote again, I will remove my downvote since this is actually useful/original code.

Comment: Edited! (You can’t convert to a Builder instance because the query parameters don’t exist on the Collection instance, and it would be counter productive just for pagination.

Comment: And the OP does ask “Is there a simpler way” without the waste of resources

Comment: Thanks for the bounty @Jesse